# How to create SQL trigger for insert for three tables

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, sql-update

I want to create SQL Trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Multi_Insert ON ITEMS, COMPONENT, LINK_INFO
FOR INSERT  
AS  
INSERT INTO Multi_Insert (ACTION, PUBLICATION_ID, ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, ITEM_TYPE, LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE, URL, SCHEMA_ID)  
SELECT 'ADD', PUBLICATION_ID, ITEM_REFERENCE_ID, ITEM_TYPE, LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE, URL, SCHEMA_ID  
FROM inserted
```

In above trigger earlier all the details where coming from one table `ITEMS`, now some values has been moved to other tables like `SCHEMA_ID` is now in `COMPONENT` and `URL` in `LINK_INFO`.

Actually on the `insert/update/delete` of above tables, we will be updating, inserting and deleting the `Multi_Insert` table, now we can write three trigger for insert event on every table insert `ITEMS`, `COMPONENT`, `LINK_INFO`, however I want to achieve this using one trigger only

Is that is possible?

Comment: what association in your tables?

Comment: ITEM_REFERENCE_ID is primary and reference key used in between these tables

Comment: Possible create view on your tables with JOIN's and then define INSTEAD OF trigger on this view.
But this demand perform action on view, not on base tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @i INT, @d INT;
SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;
SELECT @d = COUNT(*) FROM deleted;
IF @i + @d > 0
BEGIN
    IF @i > 0 AND @d = 0
        -- insert
    IF @i > 0 AND @d > 0
        -- update
    IF @i = 0 AND @d > 0
        -- delete
END
```

As i told you, i'm not so much clear about your question. And, whatsoever, i got from you question. I wrote simple query, so that you can take the reference and use it accordingly.

From the above query, `@d` and `@i` two variable declared and from the 2nd and 3rd line i'm storing the `count` (number of rows) from different tables. And, then i'm checking the value whether tables have some row or not. Then, performing the `insert`, `update` and `delete` after checking whether tables have some row or not. Now, what was the difficult part in that ?? I gave you, how you can perform all three in single `trigger` rest is up to you, how you can use them. You may also refer this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4a8241a1-d498-4ddb-834e-bbf0e38b4c0b/)

Comment: @Var..thanks, but I don't want to update multiple tables, however I want to read the values from multiple table while anything is being inserted on these three table, I want to handle it using one trigger, I don't want to create three trigger for there inserts

Comment: what you will do after reading the data from these 3 tables. You have specified your question clearly.

Comment: write your expectation and what you have tried and your current result everything otherwise your question will be closed

Comment: Yes, I want to do that, but using all the three tables, so only one trigger to update/insert/delete my table

Comment: i get the 1st part of your question (you want insert,update and delete by one trigger ) but still i'm not clear. What do you mean by `but using all the three tables ` ?

Comment: see earlier all the data where coming from one table i.e. was items, now after upgrade URL data is moved to link_info table as well as schema_id is moved to components, so my trigger will take values from these tables while inserting/updating/deleting

Comment: I am still not very clear about your logic, can you please put sample code this